# Collecting form errors to be displayed

Tags: php, error-handling, form, zend-framework

I have a piece of code that get errors from form and display to view:

```
$errors = $form->getMessages();
$msg = '';
foreach ($errors as $error)
{
    foreach ($error as $err)
    {
        $msg .= $err . '<br/>';
    }
}
$this->view->error_message = $msg;
```

It look so ugly, but now I don't have any ideas to improve it. Thank for help.

Comment: No way to use less foreach loop and get it cleaner.

Comment: It is impossible to tell without knowing the exact structure of $errors.

Answer (score 5):

You can use array_merge to reduce the array from 2-dim to 1-dim, then implode the array.

```
$this->view->error_message = 
    implode(array_reduce($form->getMessages(),
                         "array_merge", 
                         array()),
            "<br/>");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming your $errors array looks like this:

```
$errors = array(array('message 1'), array('message 2'), array('message 3'));
```

Then you could use something like this:

```
$msg = '';
foreach($errors as $inner) {
    $msg .= current($inner) . '<br />';
}
echo $msg;
// message 1<br />message 2<br />message 3<br />
```

I dont know if its more efficient than the 2 foreach loops though.

On the other hand I personally would look into modifying the getMessages() mehtod so that it returns a single array and not a multidimensional one. With a single array you just need to implode it with a 'br' :)

Comment: by using current() it not get all $error in $errors :(

Answer (score 1):

Given errors like this:

```
$errors = array(array('message 1a','message 1b'), array('message 2'), array('message 3'));
```

I you could make a function that can call itself to account for the nested arrays.

```
function showErrors($errors) {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        $msg .= (is_array($error))? showErrors($error) : $error.'<br/>';
    }
    return($msg);
}
$msg = showErrors($errors);
```

Not sure it's cleaner, but it may be more versatile. This will accommodate deeper nested arrays should the need arise. If possible, I like Pratt's suggestion of supplying a single array.